# How do I handle binding in UITableViewCells

Tags: xamarin.ios, reactiveui

I've been doing some work on an app using ReactiveUI.

My issue is with UITableViews and the reusing of cells. I tried using ReactiveTableViewSource, but that didn't seem to give me the level of customisation I wanted (custom header and footer views).

So I used UITableViewSource and UITableViewCell and implemented IViewFor. 
I then did the binding in the individual cells.

That works fine, but I'm worried about "re-binding" to the new ViewModel every time a cell is reused. I believe I've worked around it, but I'm sure there's a better way to do it.

---

Code I'm using (only the relevant bit):

```cs
public partial class FlavourTableViewCell : UITableViewCell, IViewFor<MenuItemViewModel.FlavourSetItemViewModel>
{
    public MenuItemViewModel.FlavourSetItemViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
    object IViewFor.ViewModel { get { return ViewModel; } set { ViewModel = (MenuItemViewModel.FlavourSetItemViewModel)value; } }

    List<IDisposable> bindings = new List<IDisposable> ();

    // Called when new data should be shown in cell
    internal void Update (MenuItemViewModel.FlavourSetItemViewModel data, MenuItemViewModel.FlavourSelectionEnum type)
    {
        ViewModel = data;

        // Clear old bindings
        if (bindings.Any ()) {
            bindings.ForEach (x => x.Dispose ());
            bindings.Clear ();
        }

        bindings.Add (this.Bind (ViewModel, x => x.IsSelected, view => view.SelectionButton.Selected));
    }
}
```

---

Additional info:

`FlavourSetItemViewModel` contains a list of `FlavourSetItemViewModel`. I'll try to explain below:

- FlavourSetItemViewModel - Has section name

  - FlavourSetItemViewModel - Has item name
  - FlavourSetItemViewModel - Has item name
  - FlavourSetItemViewModel - Has item name
  - FlavourSetItemViewModel - Has item name
- FlavourSetItemViewModel - Has section name

  - FlavourSetItemViewModel - Has item name

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing doesn't look wrong to me. What you could improve is using a `CompositeDisposable` instead of a List of `IDisposable`.

But you could also try using `ReactiveTableViewSource` by using your own implementation and then overriding `GetViewForHeader` to supply your own header views.

You can then bind your data to your custom table view source:

```cs
this.WhenAnyValue (view => view.ViewModel.Section1, view => view.ViewModel.Section2, (section1, section2) => new TableSectionInformation<TModel> [] {
    new TableSectionInformation<TModel, TReactiveTableViewCell> (section1, "section1cell", 44),
    new TableSectionInformation<TModel, TReactiveTableViewCell> (section2, "section2cell", 44)
})
.BindTo (tableViewSource, x => x.Data);
```

If you're using a dynamic amount of sections, you could do the following:

```cs
this.WhenAnyValue (view => view.ViewModel.TableSections)
    .Select (tableData => tableData.Select (section => new TableSectionInformation<TModel, TReactiveTableViewCell> (section, "cellIdentifier", 44)).ToArray ())
    .BindTo (tableViewSource, x => x.Data);
```

Assuming `TableData` is an 2-dimensional list of sorts.

Take care that in my sample, changes to the list(s) are not taken into account. Only changes to the property (TableSections) itself.

Comment: This looks promising. But I have a dynamic number of sections. Any hints on that?

Comment: I've added this to the answer.

Comment: Apparently not all my brain cells are working today. Could you please elaborate on the implementation of `TableSectionInformation`?

Comment: You use the supplied implementation of `TableSectionInformation`. It's just a way of supplying the `ReactiveTableViewSource` with the correct data. You create your own implementation of `ReactiveTableViewSource` to be able to override methods like `GetViewForHeader`. Or to be able to use dynamic row heights for example.

Just don't forget to replace all generic types in my examples with the correct actual types. Like `TReactiveTableViewCell` being your custom `ReactiveTableViewCell` class and `TModel` the view model which the cell has in it's `IViewFor` interface.

Comment: Could you take a look at this gist and tell me what's wrong? https://gist.github.com/3xa-henrik/9cc7005e2747af690c5fe3ab58a4a547
I get a System.Reflection.TargetException (Non-static method requires a target). It's probably something simple, but I'm just not seeing it

Comment: In the gist you linked you're not creating a new `ReactiveFlavoursDataSource`. Sorry for the late response, apparently I'm not receiving messages from SO.